# How to search a page for certain words and automatically click a button

Tags: javascript

I need to sort messages, and I can either remove them or approve them (or ignore).
I want to create a script (probably using Tampermonkey - I'm using Chrome on mac) where I could input a list of recurring words (swear words I would input) for which it removes the messages so that it can go faster, it would automatically click the remove button after if it find the word(s) in the message.
If it doesn't find anything I want it to do NOTHING, just leave the page as is.

Basically usually after I click the button the page loads again automatically and gives me the next message.

I don't really know programming, I'm mostly just around html/css and a bit of jquery, but I'm learning here and there.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Unable to understand your question.

Comment: Okay so I have a webpage that is like this

REMOVE      APPROUVE    IGNORE

messagemessagemessagemessagemessagemessage



I am moderating the messages. I sort them. I want to make a script so that repetitive message containing swearwords get clicked on 'remove' automatically.

Comment: What was I unclear about ?

Comment: Ok, so what should be the input and what should be the output

Comment: I would like to input the words I want to 'detect' to trigger the button click (swear words). If one of the words is found, it would trigger the remove button, and if it isn't, it wouldn't do anything, it would just leave the page as is.

Comment: okay, actually i was asking for some example words as input and output so that i can help.

Comment: Oh well I wouldn't want to use swear words here hahaha, but you can mark 'fdp' or 'mosh'.

Comment: What do you mean by output ? The div ? I'll check that.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle...

Comment: So here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9TP6s/

Comment: Please note that the form value '/voting/xxxxxx/..." is not static and changes for each message I moderate.

Comment: So what I want is for javascript to fetch the last <p> where the message I have to moderate shows up, and if it finds any of the words I input then it has to trigger a click on 'Abusive'.

Please note that the page refreshes automatically whenever I click on 'abusive' or 'not abusive' or 'I don't know'. So I would need it to run continuously, as there are a lot of abusive messages, and I don't want to activate the script everytime, it would be worthless.